# Angular 2 What to do when you don't want to have a selector on a page

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm very new to Angular, so sorry if this is a bit of a silly question.

Right now I have a BlogComponent, which is a CRUD system that handles my blogging engine. However this selector only appears on the `/blog` section of my website. The routing itself is done by my backend (ASP.NET Core).

When I browse to `/` I get an error in the console saying "The selector "blog" did not match any elements"

How am I supposed to fix this? Has it something to do with routing?

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have anything to with routing. The error means that Angular is looking for a component definition with a selector that matches `<blog>` (i.e. `selector: 'blog'`) but it can't find one. Typically this means that you haven't registered your `BlogComponent` in the `declarations` array of your module. Check out the [guide on modules](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html) for more.

Comment: That's because my `<blog>` is only in the `/blog` section on the page. When I navigate to `/blog` everything works correctly. However when I go to `/` it shows me that error, because of course there is no `<blog>` tag in that page. How can I tell Angular to only check for that tag in `/blog/`

Comment: Well [this](https://github.com/arnvanhoutte/arnvanhoutte/blob/master/arnvanhoutte/wwwroot/app/app.module.ts) is what my main app.module looks like. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: @user2657943 You're bootstrapping three individual components which means Angular expects to see all three of those. If you really don't want to use Angular to manage your routing (which IMO would be a big mistake), you're going to need to create and serve three separate Angular applications with the appropriate bootstraps depending on the page you're at.

Comment: Oh okay, guess I'll let angular handle my routes too then.